# how to generate tfrecord files in pure python without tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a way to generate tfrecord in python without tensorflow?
I want to convert large data , but my hadoop cluster cannot run tensorflow because of low version of glibc

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried to solve your problem (like search for file format, etc.)?

Comment: It's actually harder than it should really be. In principle, each record is a [`Example`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto) protobuf message, each of which is in turn made of [`Feature`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/core/example/feature.proto) messages, so, if you can install protocol buffers, it should be easy to build these messages. The problem is that the `TFRecord` file format is not just that.

Comment: You can check [`tensorflow/core/lib/io/record_writer.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/core/lib/io/record_writer.h) and [`tensorflow/core/lib/io/record_writer.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/core/lib/io/record_writer.cc), but essentially each example gets a header which is its length, CRC of the length, the example data itself (serialized protobuf message) and a footer, which is the CRC of the data (there's also optional compression but you can skip that). You can also look the source of the record reader.

Comment: Of course, other option would be to make the examples somewhere else and then move them to the cluster, if that is at all possible.

Comment: thank you for your answer. As your thoughts, I completed it in one day successfully. It contain two steps: 1. generate Example/Feature classes by protobuf.  2. assembling an tfrecord agreement.

Comment: 2.Assembling a tfrecord agreement.    I'll release it as soon as prossible.